# Encoded images in html using data uri not working with xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, google-app-engine, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I'm attempting to generate a PDF using xhtml2pdf on google app-engine. I've got most things working, including embedding images into the template. However this only works for publically accessable images (xhtml2pdf etches the images to embed them.) I need to be able to keep some of the images private. Because of this, I'd like to be able to embed some images directly into the html using the data uri scheme. Sadly I get an error when I do this:

The html tag in question is:

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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%2BTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2BPn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2BPn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD3%2BiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAoopGZUUszBQOpJoAWiuY1f4geHNFYrdahHvHVVOa4jVPj9oFqxW0hknI70AevUV8%2BXf7Rcm7/RtOUD3NVh%2B0VfZ50%2BOgD6Morw/Rf2hLG4lCalZmIH%2BJa9S0LxjoniGNWsL2N2P8BODQBvUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAHN%2BMPGWn%2BD9NN1dtlj9xPU183%2BLvjHrniCV47WU2tseAqHBxXq/wAaPBup%2BJLaGWwBcx9U9a4XwV8Db7UJ1n1smCAH7nc0AeTRwalq9wdiTXEjH0JrpdM%2BF3inU2Hl6dIgPdxivqvQvBeh%2BH4VjsrGMMB99lyTW%2BqqowqgfQUAfLdp8A/EkxHmtHGPc1dP7POt44u4s19MUUAfH%2Bv/AAi8TaErSG1M0a/xR81ydhqepeH9QWWCWWCaNuRnFfdbIrqVZQwPUEV85/HvwnY6bNb6raRrE0xIdVGOaAPTPhb4%2BTxhowjnIF7CMOPWvQa%2BT/gdqMtp43jhUnZKMMK%2BsKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigBCARgjNAAAwBilooAKKKKACiiigBGYIpZjgAZJr5U%2BNXjH%2B3/ERsYGzb2p2jHc1738SvEsfhrwjdTbws0qlIxnnNfH0aTatqyry8s8n6k0AesfAPw7Ld%2BIH1R0IhhGAxHevpquX8A%2BG4fDXha1tkQLKyBpD3JrqKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACo55o7eF5pWCogySe1JcXEVrbvPM4SNBlmPavnf4ofGFr4TaPozFYclXlB60Acv8XvHD%2BJ9fe1gcm0tztUA8E1q/BLwQ%2Br60urXUX%2BjW5yuR1NefeF/Dl74p1yK0gRn3sN7Y6Cvsjwv4ft/Deh29hboBsUbiO5oA2AAoAHAFLRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABUVxcQ2sLTTyLHGoyWY4FZeveKNL8O2T3N9dRrtHC7uTXzV8Qvi5f%2BJpXtLF2gsgcfKcFqAOm%2BLnxXS9jfRtGl/d9JJFPWvKfCfha%2B8W6zHZ2ysdzfO%2BOgpPDPhPVPFepJBaQuwY/NIRwK%2BrvAXgOy8G6WqIga6YfvJMc0AP8E%2BAtN8HWCpBGr3JHzyEc5rrqKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAqO4njtoHmlYKiDJJqSszxDYSanoV3aRMVeSMgEUAeV%2BI/j7p%2Bm3slrp9qbgoSC5PFcDrnx41/UVMdoq2yn%2B71rkdd8AeItL1CZJNPmkUMcOqkg1hSaJqcWd9jOuPVDQBJqWu6prUxe8upZmJ6E11fgX4czeJbtJLyeO2tAcsXYAmuK%2By3cZ/1Mo/4Camjv9St%2BEnnT2BIoA%2Bz/AAxoOieHNPS207yOBy4Iya6AMGGQQR7V8Nw%2BKtdt%2BI9RuF/4Ea3dN%2BK3irTV2pqDuP8Aa5oA%2ByKK%2BSP%2BF2eLc/8AH0PyqK4%2BM3i2eMp9s257igD64aeJPvSoPqwrKv8AxXoem5%2B1ajAhHbcK%2BOrnxt4iu2Jk1Oc59GNZjS6lqMmS08zH3JoA%2Btrr4u%2BErViDfhyP7taHh74haF4knMNjcAv/AHT1r5Eg8L65dn91p9w3/ADXq/wj%2BHmuWevJqN5E9vEnY8ZoA%2Bj6KQDAApaACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAY8Mcn341b6iqz6Tp8gIezgbPqgq5RQBkN4X0N87tMtzn/AGBVCb4f%2BGJyS%2BlQZPoK6aigDhLn4Q%2BErkkmwCZ/u1zN7%2Bz9oU8pa3uJIlPavYaKAPE/%2BGd9Lz/x/v8AlTo/2eNJVwXvpCPTFe1UUAecWPwU8KWkSq9u0rDuxrptN8EeHtKAFtpsII7sua6GigCCOztohiO3iUeyipgAowAB9KWigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP//Z' width='230' height='143' >
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamish/dev/kp3/src/libs/xhtml2pdf/tags.py", line 332, in start
    height=None)
  File "/Users/hamish/dev/kp3/src/libs/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf_reportlab.py", line 476, in __init__
    img = self.getImage()
  File "/Users/hamish/dev/kp3/src/libs/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf_reportlab.py", line 497, in getImage
    img = PmlImageReader(StringIO.StringIO(self._imgdata))
  File "/Users/hamish/dev/kp3/src/libs/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf_reportlab.py", line 343, in __init__
    self._image = self._read_image(self.fp)
  File "/Users/hamish/dev/kp3/src/libs/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf_reportlab.py", line 373, in _read_image
    return PILImage.open(fp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file fileName=<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x10503ca70>
```

Comment: Well, its looks like xhtml2pdf issue. I've a lot of issues with it, actually. It cannot process html just like browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could peek inside /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py or maybe even hack it a bit to see exactly what's the reason for upset there:

> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in
>   open
>       raise IOError("cannot identify image file")

Assuming it's an access permission issue on the private vs public files check what's the difference between the 2 access types.

If your app is statically serving both kinds of files and you allow public access via **application_readable: true** flags in the app.yaml file you need to do the same for the private ones and maybe protect them with **login: required** or **login: admin**.

If the private protection comes dynamically from your app check how exactly you do that and maybe adjust the xhtml2pdf accesses accordingly, if possible.